# Check password string strength criteria in Swift

Tags: swift, string

My password strength criteria is as below :

8 characters length
No Special Characters
Atleast 1 numeral
Atleast 1 alphabet

Comment: See [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48345922/3600709)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

update: **Xcode 8.3.2 • Swift 3.1**

```
enum PasswordError: String, Error {
    case eightCharacters
    case oneUppercase
    case oneLowercase
    case oneDecimalDigit
}

extension String {
    func validatePassword() throws  {
        guard count > 7
            else { throw PasswordError.eightCharacters }
        guard rangeOfCharacter(from: .uppercaseLetters) != nil
            else { throw PasswordError.oneUppercase }
        guard rangeOfCharacter(from: .lowercaseLetters) != nil
            else { throw PasswordError.oneLowercase }
        guard rangeOfCharacter(from: .decimalDigits) != nil
            else { throw PasswordError.oneDecimalDigit }
    }
}
```

---

```
let myPass = "12345678"

do {
    try myPass.validatePassword()
    print("valid password action")
} catch let error as PasswordError {
    print("Password error:", error) 
    switch error {
    case .eightCharacters:
        print("Needs At Least Eight Characters action")
    case .oneUppercase:
        print("Needs At Least one Uppercase action")
    case .oneLowercase:
        print("Needs At Least one Lowercase action")
    case .oneDecimalDigit:
        print("Needs At Least One DecimalDigit action")
    }
} catch {
    print("error:", error)
}
```

Comment: This could be refined by returning a specific error-message string rather than just `false` (so that the user can be informed of what criteria the candidate password actually failed on).

Comment: That we can leave as an assignment to the OP.

Comment: @LeoDabus : Can you please help me with the following requirement?

Comment: Password must be more than 6 characters, with at least one capital, numeric or special character

Comment: Your code is good at telling the user what is required but fails to specify invalid character. if we have copies for "English only" and "number or special character from %&" your code cannot do this. it can only tell what the user is missing

Comment: @CDMsocialmediasinbio There is no special character requirement in the original post. Fell free to adjust it to your needs.

Comment: in my own solution I had to create a inverted character set that excluded all English characters. that is how I detected special characters

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,}$
```

or

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?!.*[\W_\x7B-\xFF]).{8,}$
```

The first does not care about special characters, the second disallows them.

Comment: I realize the OP specifically mentions using a regex in the title, but I’m pretty sure they don’t actually want to be using a regex for this task (because it’s not going to enable them to emit any specific/useful error messages if the password fails against the criteria).

Comment: @sideshowbarker You can let the user enter the whole password and then validate it, in this case detailed message is great. Or you can validate the password after each typed character and give some visual feedback (different color of the text, for example) to show if the password is strong enough. In that case detailed error message seems excessive.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! What I did in my error message is display the criteris for a valid password. I think thats good enough. Thank you guys!

Comment: You'll need to escape the \d and \W etc. For example: \\d and \\W and so on. You could also improve the performance of the above by matching each part of the pattern the minimum number of times by replacing '.*' with '.?+'. Take a look at the cheat sheet of the Ray Wenderlich tutorial at http://cdn5.raywenderlich.com/downloads/RW-NSRegularExpression-Cheatsheet.pdf

Comment: Can not see any iOs related string syntax there