# Accept Only Letter Characters for Signup (Swift)

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform, authentication

**This was previously marked as a duplicate of another question, but what Im asking is different. Im asking how to accomplish it through an 'if' statement.**

Im creating a signup page in my app and I want it to check for letter characters only. I was planning to put it through a if statement. Something like this:

```
var allowedCharArray = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]

if usernameTextField.text.characters != (allowedCharArray Characters) && passwordTextField.text.characters != (allowedCharArray Characters) { 
//continue 
} else {
//popup error
}
```

The language I'm using is swift. How would I set up this 'if' statement? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31954533/2303865

Comment: If the link above doesn't help, let me know so I can reopen your question.

Comment: Why do you want to use an If statement? Your questions say "Is there a better way...", and the duplicate shows that.